# Line spacing for blockquotes in csquotes

Tags: line-spacing, csquotes

I would like to have a single line spacing for my blockquotes set with csquotes. After the blockquote I would like to switch back to the normal spacing I set with the setspace package.
I tried the following (see [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/hRCzEQItC6Q)):

```
\newenvironment*{singlespcquote}
{\quote\SingleSpacing}
 {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}
```

But I only get an error stating that the `\SingleSpacing` command is not known.

Edit:
Thanks to Bernard's comment I changed `\SingleSpacing` to `\singlespacing` and now it just works fine. I also added a MWE if someone would like to test it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newenvironment*{singlespcquote}
    {\quote\singlespacing}
    {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\blockquote{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
nulla pariatur. Duis aute irure. dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur} Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be a good idea to post a fully compilable document rather than code snippets, so that we can compile it to reproduce the error ourselves.

Comment: `\singlespacing` (all lowercase) is a command  from the `setspace` package, but I don't know of `\SingleSpacing`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, writing it in lower case letters was the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extreme example to illustrate what you could do:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/32ACwXI.png?1]

An explanation for why this works is given by the group that an environment opens. When you issue the `\begin{<environment>}` command, in most cases you open a group with localized definitions. Line spacing is one such definition and, as such, when you issue the `\begin{<environment>}` command, declarations are henceforth localized to whatever your input is *until* you again issue the `\end{<environment>}` command, which will close the group. When the group is closed, the compiler once again obeys the definitions in place *before* you issued `\begin{<environment>}`.

In this example, your line spacing was 5 before you (once again) opened a `spacing` environment, then you declared your spacing to be 1, which was at that point localized between the secondary `\begin{spacing}` and `\end{spacing}` commands. You can do this indefinitely, and it can also apply to text (e.g. `\textit{This is some text that is all italicized, \textrm{but now we're using the roman style for a little bit,} to then again go back to italicized text}.` - this uses the same principle but doesn't in fact open a new group*, though).

* = correct me if I'm wrong

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newenvironment*{singlespcquote}
    {\begin{spacing}{1}\quote}
    {\endquote\end{spacing}}

\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{5}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\blockquote{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
nulla pariatur. Duis aute irure. dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur} Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```